# Union and intersection of sets and their complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This will sound as a stupid question, but I need to get if I have gotten all right.

Consider $A$ the set of even natural numbers; $B$ the set of natural numbers multiple of $5$. Then I have:

$$A^c = \text{set of odd natural numbers} = \{1, 3, 5, 7, ...\}$$
$$B^c = \text{set of natural numbers not multiple of five} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, ...\}$$
$$A\cap B = \text{set of even naturals multiple of five} = \{0, 10, 20, 30, ...\}$$
$$A\cup B = \text{set of even naturals or multiple of five} = \{0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, ...\}$$
$$A^c \cap B^c = \text{set of odd naturals not multiple of five} = \{1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, ...\}$$
$$A^c \cup B^c = \text{set of odd naturals or not multiple of five} = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...\} = \mathbb{N}\backslash\{ 0 \}$$

is this all correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Your last one is not correct.  Note that $10$ is not odd and is a multiple of $5$.

Comment: @RobertShore Oh, gosh! Then I have to exclude $10, 20, 30$ and so on... This changes everything. Thank you!

Comment: I agree with @RobertShore. $A^c\cup B^c=\{n\in\mathbb{N}~|~n~\nmid~10\}=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{10n~|~n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Thank you! I was indeed trying to prove, with an example, that the complement of the intersection is the union of the complements!

Comment: @Numb3rs I am not sure what you mean by "prove, with an example". Examples cannot give you a proof, unless your example is actually a *counterexample* to something.

Comment: 1) Before taking complements, you need to say where (here: in $E:=\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$). 2) If you want to convince yourself (rather than "prove") with an example, take a simpler looking one (though as "general"): $E=\{1,2,3,4\},A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,3\}.$